# Can I allow punctuation to run past fill-column?

Tags: fill-column

In typography, there's a practice called 'protrusion' (or [hanging punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_punctuation)) that allows certain symbols to hang off the end of the margin:

[image: protrusion]

I'd like to do the same thing for my text documents.

Can I change `fill-paragraph` (and friends?) to ignore end-of-line punctuation (`.?!:;,'"-`) when it fills the paragraph?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can really call protrusion (subtle shifting of trailing punctuation) of justified text comparable to ignoring trailing punctuation when hard-wrapping text (which doesn't justify text by default, making the effect essentially invisible).  Perhaps you'd like to add that this applies to the justified variant of `fill-paragraph`?

Comment: @wasamasa Protrusion still exists for flush left text blocks.

Comment: Does it apply to the left edge of the text then?

Comment: @wasamasa Unless you're dealing with an RTL language and editor (which, while supported, I feel is out-of-scope), it doesn't make sense. If you have a flush right block and you 'run out of room' on the left margin (i.e., column 0), you can't exactly put the punctuation in column -1. (I suppose you could shift the right margin to (1+ fill-column), but that would change the filling and you could get caught in a loop.)

Comment: Well, no, I'm trying to understand how exactly the protrusion feature is supposed to work for something that's not fully justified text.

Comment: @wasamasa In terms of implementation: unfill. jump to fill-column. if point is looking at a single character of punctuation and then whitespace, skip forward. else if in the middle of a word, skip backward. newline, repeat.

Comment: You need to write a custom predicate function for variable `fill-nobreak-predicate`. In order to get the right behaviour, I think you'll need to establish exactly how function `fill-move-to-break-point` behaves when calling `(fill-nobreak-p)`.

Comment: @phils is correct. To be able to do this, we need to allow moving forward in `fill-move-to-break-point` which currently doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3):

Aha, I have the solution! Put this somewhere in your `.emacs`/`.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
(define-advice current-fill-column (:filter-return (rtn) protrusion)
  "Advice to allow hanging punctuation when filling text."
  ;; Get the character after the proposed cutoff point
  (let ((end-char (char-after (1+ rtn))))
    (if (and end-char
             ;; Check if character is in the “punctuation” syntax table…
             (or (eq (char-syntax end-char) ?.)
                 ;; …or is any of these characters (feel free to add more)
                 (memq end-char (string-to-list ".,!?;:-"))))
        ;; If so, return the original value, plus one.
        (1+ rtn)
      ;; Otherwise, do nothing and return the original value.
      rtn)))
```

I’ve tested this with `fill-paragraph`, and it should work for all the fill functions (since they all use `current-fill-column` when processing each line). I hope you like it!